# Residual norm for iterative scheme

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

Consider a linear system $A\vec{x} = \vec{b}$, where $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times{}m}$ is non-singular and positive definite. Given the following iteration scheme
$\vec{x}^{(k+1)} = \vec{x}^{(k)} + \alpha\vec{r}^{(k)},\quad\quad \vec{r}^{(k)} = \vec{b} - A\vec{x}^{(k)}$
where $\alpha$ is chosen to minimize $||\vec{r}^{(k+1)}||_2$. Prove that
$\frac{||\vec{r}^{(k+1)}||_2}{||\vec{r}^{(k)}||_2} \le \Big(1 - \frac{\lambda_{min}(M)^2}{\lambda_{max}(A^TA)}\Big)^{1/2}$
where $M = \frac{1}{2}(A+A^T)$ is the symmetric part of A.

My solution so far:
$\vec{r}^{(k+1)} = \vec{b} - A\vec{x}^{(k+1)} = \vec{b} - A(\vec{x}^{(k)} + \alpha\vec{r}^{(k)}) = \vec{r}^{(k)} - A\alpha{}\vec{r}^{(k)}$
$\Rightarrow \vec{r}^{(k+1)} = (I-A\alpha)\vec{r}^{(k)}$
$\frac{||\vec{r}^{(k+1)}||_2}{||\vec{r}^{(k)}||_2} \le \frac{||I-A\alpha||_2\cdot{}||\vec{r}^{(k)}||_2}{||\vec{r}^{(k)}||_2}$
$\Rightarrow \frac{||\vec{r}^{(k+1)}||_2}{||\vec{r}^{(k)}||_2} \le ||I-A\alpha||_2$

Beyond this, I'm not sure how to incorporate the symmetric part. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First you need the expression for the step length $\alpha_k$ which minimises the norm of the residual $r_{k+1}=r_k-\alpha_kAr_k$ (note that $\alpha$ depends generally on $k$). Since
$$\tag{1}
\|r_{k+1}\|_2^2=\|r_k\|_2^2-2\alpha_k(r_k,Ar_k)+\alpha_k^2\|Ar_k\|_2^2
$$
(where $(\cdot,\cdot)$ is the Euclidean inner product), we have that the norm of $r_{k+1}$ is minimal if
$$
\alpha_k = \frac{(r_k,Ar_k)}{\|Ar_k\|_2^2}.
$$
Putting this back to (1) gives
$$
\|r_{k+1}\|_2^2=\|r_k\|_2^2-\frac{(r_k,Ar_k)^2}{\|Ar_k\|_2^2}.
$$
Hence
$$
\|r_{k+1}\|_2^2=\|r_k\|_2^2-\frac{(r_k,Ar_k)^2}{\|Ar_k\|_2^2\|r_k\|_2^2}\|r_k\|_2^2
$$
so
$$\tag{2}
\frac{\|r_{k+1}\|_2}{\|r_k\|_2}=\sqrt{1-\frac{(r_k,Ar_k)^2}{\|Ar_k\|_2^2\|r_k\|_2^2}}
=\sqrt{1-\frac{(r_k,Mr_k)^2}{\|Ar_k\|_2^2\|r_k\|_2^2}}.
$$
In the real case, it is easy to check (using the symmetric of the inner product), that for any real vector $v$, we have $(v,Av)=\frac{1}{2}(v,Av)+\frac{1}{2}(v,A^Tv)=(v,Mv)$.
In order to obtain the upper bound for the convergence factor, we need to cook some reasonable lower bound for the second term in the square root on the right-hand side.
Here's the recipe:
$$
\frac{(r_k,Mr_k)^2}{\|Ar_k\|_2^2\|r_k\|_2^2}
=\left[\frac{(r_k,Mr_k)}{(r_k,r_k)}\frac{\|r_k\|_2}{\|Ar_k\|_2}\right]^2
\geq\left[\min_{v\neq 0}\frac{(v,Mv)}{(v,v)}\right]^2
\left[\max_{v\neq 0}\frac{(v,A^TAv)}{(v,v)}\right]^{-1}
$$
Now using the Courant-Fisher theorem, we can bound the minimum/maximum of the Rayleigh quotients using the minimal/maximal eigenvalue:
$$
\frac{(r_k,Mr_k)^2}{\|Ar_k\|_2^2\|r_k\|_2^2}
\geq\frac{\lambda_{\min}(M)^2}{\lambda_{\max}(A^TA)}.
$$
Put it back to (2) and it's done.